# Approach for CSS responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Disclaimer: I am not a designer. I don't know enough about responsive CSS approaches. Go easy on me! I am a developer that is trying his hands to create an adoptive layout.

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3. Here is the layout I need in the Portrait mode:

[image: Portrait mode image]

And here is what it should change to in the Landscape mode:

[image]

And here is the "layout algorithm" I have in my mind:

- If the width of the screen is higher than 768px, use the landscape layout, split the screen into 2 (Applicable in landscape mode for phones and tablets)
- Else, if the height is greater than 400, use the portrait layout squeeze everything to fit.
- Else, display the landscape mode, but only the graph, with a button to present an overlay with the same options. (not included in the screenshot above.)

Now my questions:

- Can this be done using CSS alone? If so, how? (The buttons in the portrait mode move above and below the chart, and in landscape, distribute themselves evenly.)
- Otherwise, what is the best approach to use minimal javascript to achieve this responsive layout.

Comment: This can be done using CSS media queries - these allow you to define different blocks of CSS that are based on different layout measurements. There are plenty of tutorials on this topic.

Comment: It's also pretty well documented on the Bootstrap resource site [[1](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)].

Comment: There is no breakpoint in Boostrap between 0-767px, so this cannot be done with Bootstrap out of the box, you'll need to add the css discussed here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203 and also use some jQuery to clone the position of the chart since it comes after the "In Country" row of buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** http://www.bootply.com/104401

Create a CSS media query for the breakpoint between portrait and landscape (for example this is 480px on iPhone). This can be used to pull the pie chart to the right:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .push{float:right;}
}
```

Then another query to tell Bootstrap to stack the columns on portrait:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .breakpoint{width:100%;}
}
```

Use `push` and `breakpoint` classes accordingly as shown in the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/104401).

Comment: glyphicon-heart glyphicon-heart glyphicon-heart :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use CSS3 media queries. check for device-width and device-height respectively.